# Socialauth API 4.3 with Google Oauth 2.0

Tags: api, socialauth

Does anyone know how to use Brickred Socialauth API 4.3 in servlets with Google Oauth 2.0?
Where could I get the *consumer_secret* and *consumer_key*?

Was using the API successful at your side?

Answer (score 4):

The instructions available on the BrickRed wiki no longer work as you have already found out. The following should work assuming:

A. You are using socialauth 4.2+. I tested these with socialauth 4.4.
B. You are trying to configure your own domain and not using the brickred domain for testing.
C. You are creating a web application, else adjust accordingly

1. First register your application on Google Cloud console:
   a. Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project
   b. Login
   c. Create a new project
   d. APIs & Auth > Credentials
   e. Create New Client ID ( Application Type: Web Application, Authorized redirect URL: `http://YOUR_HOST_NAME/socialauth.html`)
2. Modify brickred properties.xml
   Replace 
   `<prop key="www.google.com.consumer_key">opensource.brickred.com</prop>`
   `<prop key="www.google.com.consumer_secret">YC06FqhmCLWvtBg/O4W/aJfj</prop>`
   with
   `<prop key="googleapis.com.consumer_key">CLIENT ID created in Step 1.e above</prop>`
   `<prop key="googleapis.com.consumer_secret">Client Secret created in Step 1.e above </prop>`

If you are not using Spring, modify oauth_consumer.properties

Modify the link in your application where the user clicks on to start the contacts import process:
change
`?id=google`

to

`?id=googleplus`

Hope this helps

Comment: Where do you get the consumer_secret? I understand that the consumer_key is the CLIENT ID, but what is the consumer_secret?

Comment: Is your application a web application? If yes, did you create a new client ID for web application?

Comment: It's an installed application - for Android. I've created a new client ID, for Android (and for web even though it's probably irrelevant)

Comment: If you still haven't found your secret key then you may want to download the file. The secret key is inside the file.

Comment: Negative. The secret is not inside the file. The only item in there is a map called "installed" with key:values of "auth_uri", "token_uri", "client_email", "client_x59_cert_url", "client_id" and "auth_provider_x509_cert_url"

Comment: i have the same problem, cannot find consumer_secret, the downloaded json doesn't contain consumer_secret

Answer (score 0):

You can register your app to use Google OAuth at:

> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#registeringyourapp

from where you get your "secret / key".

I have successfully implemented SocialAuth with Facebook and it worked properly. I still don't have any experience implementing it with google OAuth2 but it should work. [Their CDI](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/CDISample) example does authenticate with Google, I am just not sure if using Oauth1 or Oauth2.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat - Yes it's a web application and I had to create a developer facebook account to make it work properly. After creating the developer account I received secret / key to use in my app.

Answer (score 0):

For people who cannot find the consumer_secret, I found a solution:

> socialauth is using web flow. So if you are socialauth-android you need to create web application instead of installed application.

So even for an Android App, you still need create a Client ID for web project. The secret will be displayed in page directly!