# How to solve socialauth-android (by 3pillarlabs) and Google Accounts/Google+ using OAuth2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, socialauth

I'm building an Android application where users should be able to login to the application using an email/password combination (no brainer) or via their preferred social network.

I've implemented the `socialAuth` library for Android from **3pillarlabs** ([found on Github](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android)) and have successfully been able to implement code for sign in via Facebook and Twitter. It's simple: you create an app, copy the key and secret into the properties file in your Android project, add a few lines of code and bam! You are able to login to the application using Facebook or Twitter.

Trying this with **Google Accounts** deemed to be a lot more difficult because [the guide they provide](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Google) is out of date - it seems to use OAuth (version 1) and not OAuth2.0. I've had difficulty trying to understand how to do this with OAuth2.0 and the `socialAuth` library. I don't want to do as much work as suggested on Google's page for [implementing application sign in with Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started), if it can only be a few lines when using the `socialAuth` library.

My main issue is identifying the `consumer_secret`. When you create an application on the **Google Developer Console**, you are directed to a screen where you activate relevant APIs and then you set permissions - you create an OAuth Client ID (which is your `consumer_key` in the `socialAuth` properties file), but where do you find your `consumer_secret`?

I've learnt that using **Google+** you could have a sort of `callBack` send you an authentication code, but I don't understand what it is that should be happening.

[This solution helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21819385/956975), but I still don't know where to get the consumer_secret (apparently created in step 1):

```
1.  First register your application on Google Cloud console:
  a. Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project 
  b. Login
  c. Create a new project
  d. APIs & Auth > Credentials
  e. Create New Client ID ( Application Type: Web Application, Authorized redirect URL: http://YOUR_HOST_NAME/socialauth.html)

2.  Modify brickred properties.xml
  Replace 
  <prop key="www.google.com.consumer_key">opensource.brickred.com</prop>
  <prop key="www.google.com.consumer_secret">YC06FqhmCLWvtBg/O4W/aJfj</prop>

  with

  <prop key="googleapis.com.consumer_key">CLIENT ID created in Step 1.e above</prop>
  <prop key="googleapis.com.consumer_secret">Client Secret created in Step 1.e above </prop>

If you are not using Spring, modify oauth_consumer.properties

Modify the link in your application where the user clicks on to start the contacts import process:
change
  ?id=google

to

  ?id=googleplus
```

Has anyone implemented the `socialAuth` library for Android from **3pillarlabs** and figured out how to login to your application using **Google Accounts** or **Google+** and **OAuth2.0**? Where do you get the `consumer_secret`?

Something that confuses me, for example is this found on the Google Developer Console documentation regarding [Setting up OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2)

> Setting up OAuth 2.0
>
> To use OAuth 2.0 in your application, you need an OAuth 2.0 client ID,
>   which your application uses when requesting an OAuth 2.0 access token.
>   When you register an application in the Google Developers Console, you
>   can generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
>
> To find your application's client ID and client secret, and set a
>   redirect URI, expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section.
>
> To deactivate the client ID, delete the application from the
>   Developers Console.

How do you "expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section" ? Here is a screenshot of this screen:

[image]

Comment: check wiki for google plus guide. hope it helps. The google plus provider is for oauth2.0 and google provider is for for oauth1.0

Comment: @marienke did it work for you? Can you please help, I'm stuck in the same boat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having this problem, and just figured it out. Go to your developer console and click on the following 2 things:
[image]

The JSON file contains your secret, after the key "client_secret", and the api key is listed after "client_id". The file is a bit difficult to read, so copy the text out of the file using notepad or something and paste it into here:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

It'll organize the information for you, then click on the 'viewer' tab and the data will be nice and easy to see, like so:
[image]
Doing this got it working with socialauth-android for me, kind of, but I've actually been running into a redirect_uri_mismatch error after that, so lemme know if you run into the same thing afterwards.

Comment: I'm  too facing the same problem...have u found the solution for this redirect_uri_mismatch error ?

Comment: I tested out the samples provided by the socialauth makers, and google+ auth doesn't work for those either. I suspect it hasn't been updated for Google's OAuth 2.0. I plan on just fixing it myself and pull requesting it if they don't fix it soon. Problem with the source, not our code, though.